# Как узнавать какой пользователь сейчас использует бота?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Разрабатываю бота с помощью библиотеки aiogram. Бот сделан так, чтобы им пользовались несколько пользователей, для каждого я создаю экземпляр класса и вношу в БД.

Вопрос: как мне узнавать какой пользователь сейчас использует бота и как настроить работу бота, чтобы им пользовались сразу несколько людей, которые будут использовать разные разделы.

Comment: Не совсем понял, что за экземпляр класса вы такой делаете, дак еще и в бд его вносите, но чтобы узнать кто сейчас попал в хендер достаточно проверка типа `if message.from_user.id == ...: ...`

Comment: у меня в боте есть регистрация пользователей, и из-за этого мне нужен класс пользователя + БД. Насчет проверки, можно с помощью цикла проходиться по всем пользователям, которые щас в боте, выбирать нужного, и именно для него вычислять что-то и отправлять ему ответ. Будет ли это эффективным решением?

Comment: Что? Нет! Что значит пройтись по всем пользователям? Вы в хендлере имеете только ОДНОГО пользователя. Вы можете пройтись так только по бд.

Comment: Наверное вы неправильно поняли меня. Приведу пример. В боте есть кнопка для расчета каких-то значений. Как только пользователь нажимает на эту кнопку я его вношу в список пользователей для расчета, так как мне нужно будет отслежить что он занимается именно вычислениями. И как только он их закончил я его убираю из этого списка

Comment: Вы вроде используйте айограм, разве не было бы легче просто юзать fsm для этого, вместо целой бд? Вы бы не делали лишних запросов и сразу же получали данные как только юзер нажмёт кнопку

Comment: ам. Не знаю что такое fsm. Можете скинуть пример использования, возможно я заменю бд

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O_pPNlXMzsw - ютубовский гайд, https://mastergroosha.github.io/aiogram-2-guide/fsm/ - инфа в текстовке

Comment: Спасибо большое)